# How to break service call with huge list of account numbers

Tags: c#

For example if list has 40 account numbers how to break it to two request of 20 each and add reponse back to list

```
 public async Task<ListInformation> RetrieveInformation(List<long> AccountNumber)
    {
        ListInformationreturn Val = new ListInformation();
        var keys = new List_Type();
        AccountNumber.ForEach(x => { keys.Add(x.ToString()); });
        var response = await AccountRequestAsync(keys);

        });
    }
```

Comment: You get teh Lenght/Count. You split it into however many parts you want. Then you make a outer loop going over the "batches" or "chunks", and inner loops going over the 20 entries in the chunk/batch. Finally make the outer one a Paralell.Foreach. But Lambdas can cause some issues with variable capture, IIRC.

Comment: Actually, I just realized that merge sort does something like that: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort | Split into Parition. Process each partition seperately. You can even find recursive implementations, where each "level" can decide wich sort it will apply to it's subset. Basically if you got X or less element, you use a simple sort. If you got X or more elements? Split the array and recusively call the function for each part - then merge the results.

Comment: any sample code will work.I am new to API's.

Comment: This has nothing to do with API's. Just basic splitting of collections. And then very much *not basic* multitasking (Multitasking is never really simple).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this this:

```
public async Task<ListInformation> RetrieveInformation(List<long> AccountNumber)
    {
        ListInformationreturn Val = new ListInformation();

        int skip = 0; //default
        const int take = 20;
        do
        {
            var keys = new List_Type();
            AccountNumber.Skip(skip).Take(take).ForEach(x => { keys.Add(x.ToString()); });
            var response = await AccountRequestAsync(keys);

            });
            skip += keys.Count();

        }
        while (AccountNumber.Count() != skip);
    }
```

Or you can make a property with number of elements that you want to take, instead of

```
const int take = 20;
```

And important thing we have here:

```
skip += keys.Count();
```

We always have to add to a **skip** property the count of handled keys, instead of **take** count.

And add your response to result like this:

```
ListInformationReturn result = new ListInformation();
result.Add(response)
```

But actually i don't know you response type, so this is just an example

Comment: How to call the service if i have 1 or more account numbers.